# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.fundamentos.abisu.chatfirebase.Mensaje

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

Cree la base de datos en firebase y pude hacer una sola inserción, pero al hacerla obtuve la siguiente excepción de firebase

```
Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.fundamentos.abisu.chatfirebase.Mensaje
```

Se supone que mi error esta en esta linea

> Mensaje mensaje = dataSnapshot.getValue(Mensaje.class);

del main activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CircleImageView fotoPerfil;
    private TextView nombre;
    private RecyclerView rvMensajes;
    private EditText txtMensajes;
    private ImageButton btnMensajes;

    private MensajeAdapter mensajeAdapter;

    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fotoPerfil = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.fotoPerfil);
        nombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        rvMensajes = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvMensajes);
        txtMensajes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMensajes);
        btnMensajes = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMensajes);

        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("chat");//Sala de chat (nombre)

        mensajeAdapter = new MensajeAdapter(this);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rvMensajes.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        rvMensajes.setAdapter(mensajeAdapter);

        btnMensajes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                databaseReference.push().setValue(new Mensaje(txtMensajes.getText().toString(),nombre.getText().toString(),"","1","00:00"));
            }
        });

        mensajeAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                setScrollbar();
            }
        });

        databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                **Mensaje mensaje = dataSnapshot.getValue(Mensaje.class);**
                mensajeAdapter.addMensaje(mensaje);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void setScrollbar() {
        rvMensajes.scrollToPosition(mensajeAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
    }
}
```

Pero no se cual es el problema realmente, estas son mis clases MensajeAdpater

```
package com.fundamentos.abisu.chatfirebase;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MensajeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HolderMensaje> {

    private List<Mensaje> listMensaje = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    public MensajeAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void addMensaje(Mensaje mensaje){
        listMensaje.add(mensaje);
        notifyItemInserted(listMensaje.size());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HolderMensaje onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_view_mensajes,viewGroup,false);
        return new HolderMensaje(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HolderMensaje holderMensaje, int i) {
        holderMensaje.getNombre().setText(listMensaje.get(i).getNombre());
        holderMensaje.getMensaje().setText(listMensaje.get(i).getMensaje());
        holderMensaje.getHora().setText(listMensaje.get(i).getHora());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listMensaje.size();
    }
}
```

mi clase Mensaje

```
package com.fundamentos.abisu.chatfirebase;

public class Mensaje {
    private String mensaje;
    private String nombre;
    private String fotoPerfil;
    private String tipoMensaje;
    private String hora;

    public Mensaje() {
    }

    public Mensaje(String mensaje, String nombre, String fotoPerfil, String tipoMensaje, String hora) {
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.fotoPerfil = fotoPerfil;
        this.tipoMensaje = tipoMensaje;
        this.hora = hora;
    }

    public String getMensaje() {
        return mensaje;
    }

    public void setMensaje(String mensaje) {
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getFotoPerfil() {
        return fotoPerfil;
    }

    public void setFotoPerfil(String fotoPerfil) {
        this.fotoPerfil = fotoPerfil;
    }

    public String getTipoMensaje() {
        return tipoMensaje;
    }

    public void setTipoMensaje(String tipoMensaje) {
        this.tipoMensaje = tipoMensaje;
    }

    public String getHora() {
        return hora;
    }

    public void setHora(String hora) {
        this.hora = hora;
    }
}
```

mi clase HolderMensaje

```
package com.fundamentos.abisu.chatfirebase;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class HolderMensaje extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView nombre, mensaje, hora;
    private CircleImageView fotoMensaje;

    public HolderMensaje(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.msgNombre);
        mensaje = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.msgMensaje);
        hora = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.msgHora);
        fotoMensaje = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.msgFotoPerfil);
    }

    public TextView getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(TextView nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public TextView getMensaje() {
        return mensaje;
    }

    public void setMensaje(TextView mensaje) {
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
    }

    public TextView getHora() {
        return hora;
    }

    public void setHora(TextView hora) {
        this.hora = hora;
    }

    public CircleImageView getFotoMensaje() {
        return fotoMensaje;
    }

    public void setFotoMensaje(CircleImageView fotoMensaje) {
        this.fotoMensaje = fotoMensaje;
    }
}
```

Esta es la captura de mi base de datos de firebase con el unico registro que pude hacer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las reglas de la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: publica tu base de datos en Firebase asi te podemos ayudar

Comment: acabo de subir una captura de mi base de datos de firebase ¿es suficiente con eso?

Comment: holderMensaje.getNombre().setText(listMensaje.get(i).getNombre()); esa linea esta mal, deberias crear una clase dentro de tu adapter que extienda de ViewHolder y setear ahi los id de los textos con itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombretextview);

Comment: Gracias, funciono perfectamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en esta linea

```
holderMensaje.getNombre().setText(listMensaje.get(i).getNombre());
```

Para solucionarlo deberias crear una clase dentro de tu adapter que extienda de ViewHolder y setear ahi los id de los textos con

```
itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombretextview);
```